# How to use error correction when iterating through a json array

Tags: python, arrays, json

I am trying to extract the values associated with the keys 'techniqueID' and 'comment'. The issue I am running in to is that the after retrieving the value associated with the first 'comment' key (under "techniqueID": "T1212"), there is not a 'comment' key in the next section of the array. This is causing the error **Exception has occurred: KeyError 'comment'**. Should I be attempting to use an if in statement to match first, or is there a simpler way to handle this error? The end goal is to have all values associated with 'techniqueID' and all values associated with 'comment'.

**The following is the python code I am using:**

```
import json

with open('M1013-enterprise-layer.json') as mitigation_ids:
     mitigation_json = json.load(mitigation_ids)

for technique in mitigation_json['techniques']:
     print(technique['techniqueID'], [technique['comment']])
```

**The following is the JSON data I am using:**

```
{
  "description": "Enterprise techniques mitigated by Application Developer Guidance, ATT&CK mitigation M1013 (v1.1)",   
  "name": "Application Developer Guidance (M1013)",
  "domain": "enterprise-attack",
  "versions": {
    "layer": "4.4",
    "attack": "14",
    "navigator": "4.8.1"
  },
  "techniques": [
    {
      "techniqueID": "T1212",
      "comment": "Application developers should consider taking measures to validate authentication requests by enabling one-time passwords, providing timestamps or sequence numbers for messages sent, using digital signatures, and/or using 
random session keys.(Citation: Comparitech Replay Attack)(Citation: Bugcrowd Replay Attack)",
      "score": 1,
      "color": "#66b1ff",
      "showSubtechniques": false
    },
    {
      "techniqueID": "T1564",
      "showSubtechniques": true
    },
    {
      "techniqueID": "T1564.009",
      "comment": "Configure applications to use the application bundle structure which leverages the /Resources folder location.(Citation: Apple App Security Overview) ",
      "score": 1,
      "color": "#66b1ff",
      "showSubtechniques": true
    },
    {
      "techniqueID": "T1574",
      "comment": "When possible, include hash values in manifest files to help prevent side-loading of malicious libraries.(Citation: FireEye DLL Side-Loading)",
      "score": 1,
      "color": "#66b1ff",
      "showSubtechniques": true
    },
    {
      "techniqueID": "T1574.002",
      "comment": "When possible, include hash values in manifest files to help prevent side-loading of malicious libraries.(Citation: FireEye DLL Side-Loading)",
      "score": 1,
      "color": "#66b1ff",
      "showSubtechniques": true
    },
    {
      "techniqueID": "T1559",
      "comment": "Enable the Hardened Runtime capability when developing applications. Do not include the com.apple.security.get-task-allow entitlement with the value set to any variation of true. ",
      "score": 1,
      "showSubtechniques": true
    },
    {
      "techniqueID": "T1559.003",
      "comment": "Enable the Hardened Runtime capability when developing applications. Do not include the com.apple.security.get-task-allow entitlement with the value set to any variation of true. ",
      "score": 1,
      "color": "#66b1ff",
      "showSubtechniques": true
    },
    {
      "techniqueID": "T1647",
      "comment": "Ensure applications are using Apple's developer guidance which enables hardened runtime.(Citation: Apple Developer Doco Hardened Runtime)",
      "score": 1,
      "color": "#66b1ff",
      "showSubtechniques": false
    },
    {
      "techniqueID": "T1593",
      "comment": "Application developers uploading to public code repositories should be careful to avoid publishing sensitive information such as credentials and API keys.",
      "score": 1,
      "showSubtechniques": true
    },
    {
      "techniqueID": "T1593.003",
      "comment": "Application developers uploading to public code repositories should be careful to avoid publishing sensitive information such as credentials and API keys.",
      "score": 1,
      "color": "#66b1ff",
      "showSubtechniques": true
    },
    {
      "techniqueID": "T1078",
      "comment": "Ensure that applications do not store sensitive data or credentials insecurely. (e.g. plaintext credentials in code, published credentials in repositories, or credentials in public cloud storage).",
      "score": 1,
      "color": "#66b1ff",
      "showSubtechniques": false
    }
  ],
  "gradient": {
    "colors": [
      "#ffffff",
      "#66b1ff"
    ],
    "minValue": 0,
    "maxValue": 1
  },
  "legendItems": [
    {
      "label": "mitigated by Application Developer Guidance",
      "color": "#66b1ff"
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `print(technique['techniqueID'], [technique.get('comment', '')])`, prints an empty string as default in case there is no comment.

Comment: the `json` file is written badly and invalid. This breaks the code.

Comment: they'd get other errors if that was the case - the test data data must be incomplete

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify it was a quick snippet. I was able to extract the data needed and create a new JSON. I'm a bit stuck on removing \n that shows up in the string that is the value to the 'comment' key. strip and replace are not working, but I should be able to figure that out.

Comment: @TrashThrash, removing the `\n` is quite simple too, but probably best opened as a new question since this question is answered.

Comment: I quickly realized that all \n that I found were stating the same Windows file location. The question has been completely answered now.

Answer (score 0):

The json file in the original question is invalid. I know this because i stuck the text it into a linter and quickly found 3 errors.

I have corrected the errors:

1. overlapping line
2. an unclosed []
3. unclosed {}

And finally, you can use the `get()` method for dicts which conveniently checks if a key exists.

So this is an example of what might work with fixes.

```py
import json


json_data = '''
{
    "description": "Enterprise techniques mitigated by Application Developer Guidance, ATT&CK mitigation M1013 (v1.1)",   
    "name": "Application Developer Guidance (M1013)",
    "domain": "enterprise-attack",
    "versions": {
      "layer": "4.4",
      "attack": "14",
      "navigator": "4.8.1"
    },
    "techniques": [
      {
        "techniqueID": "T1212",
        "comment": "Application developers should consider taking measures to validate authentication requests by enabling one-time passwords, providing timestamps or sequence numbers for messages sent, using digital signatures, and/or using random session keys.(Citation: Comparitech Replay Attack)(Citation: Bugcrowd Replay Attack)",
        "score": 1,
        "color": "#66b1ff",
        "showSubtechniques": false
      },
      {
        "techniqueID": "T1564",
        "showSubtechniques": true
      },
      {
        "techniqueID": "T1564.009",
        "comment": "Configure applications to use the application bundle structure which leverages the /Resources folder location.(Citation: Apple App Security Overview) ",
        "score": 1,
        "color": "#66b1ff",
        "showSubtechniques": true
      },
      {
        "techniqueID": "T1574",
        "comment": "When possible, include hash values in manifest files to help prevent side-loading of malicious libraries.(Citation: FireEye DLL Side-Loading)",
        "score": 1,
        "color": "#66b1ff",
        "showSubtechniques": true
      },
      {
        "techniqueID": "T1574.002",
        "comment": "When possible, include hash values in manifest files to help prevent side-loading of malicious libraries.(Citation: FireEye DLL Side-Loading)",
        "score": 1,
        "color": "#66b1ff",
        "showSubtechniques": true
      },
      {
        "techniqueID": "T1559",
        "comment": "Enable the Hardened Runtime capability when developing applications. Do not include the com.apple.security.get-task-allow entitlement with the value set to any variation of true. ",
        "score": 1,
        "showSubtechniques": true
      },
      {
        "techniqueID": "T1559.003",
        "comment": "Enable the Hardened Runtime capability when developing applications. Do not include the com.apple.security.get-task-allow entitlement with the value set to any variation of true. ",
        "score": 1,
        "color": "#66b1ff",
        "showSubtechniques": true
      },
      {
        "techniqueID": "T1647",
        "comment": "Ensure applications are using Apple's developer guidance which enables hardened runtime.(Citation: Apple Developer Doco Hardened Runtime)",
        "score": 1,
        "color": "#66b1ff",
        "showSubtechniques": false
      },
      {
        "techniqueID": "T1593",
        "comment": "Application developers uploading to public code repositories should be careful to avoid publishing sensitive information such as credentials and API keys.",
        "score": 1,
        "showSubtechniques": true
      },
      {
        "techniqueID": "T1593.003",
        "comment": "Application developers uploading to public code repositories should be careful to avoid publishing sensitive information such as credentials and API keys.",
        "score": 1,
        "color": "#66b1ff",
        "showSubtechniques": true
      },
      {
        "techniqueID": "T1078",
        "comment": "Ensure that applications do not store sensitive data or credentials insecurely. (e.g. plaintext credentials in code, published credentials in repositories, or credentials in public cloud storage).",
        "score": 1,
        "color": "#66b1ff",
        "showSubtechniques": false
      }
    ],
    "gradient": {
      "colors": [
        "#ffffff",
        "#66b1ff"
      ],
      "minValue": 0,
      "maxValue": 1
    },
    "legendItems": [
      {
        "label": "mitigated by Application Developer Guidance",
        "color": "#66b1ff"
      }]
}
'''


mitigation_dict = json.loads(json_data)

for technique in mitigation_dict['techniques']:
    technique:dict
    print(technique['techniqueID'], technique.get('comment', '--- nothing is there ---'))
```

which returns this:

```
T1212 Application developers should consider taking measures to validate authentication requests by enabling one-time passwords, providing timestamps or sequence numbers for messages sent, using digital signatures, and/or using random session keys.(Citation: Comparitech Replay Attack)(Citation: Bugcrowd Replay Attack)
T1564 --- nothing is there ---
T1564.009 Configure applications to use the application bundle structure which leverages the /Resources folder location.(Citation: Apple App Security Overview)
T1574 When possible, include hash values in manifest files to help prevent side-loading of malicious libraries.(Citation: FireEye DLL Side-Loading)
T1574.002 When possible, include hash values in manifest files to help prevent side-loading of malicious libraries.(Citation: FireEye DLL Side-Loading)
T1559 Enable the Hardened Runtime capability when developing applications. Do not include the com.apple.security.get-task-allow entitlement with the value set to any variation of true.
T1559.003 Enable the Hardened Runtime capability when developing applications. Do not include the com.apple.security.get-task-allow entitlement with the value set to any variation of true.
T1647 Ensure applications are using Apple's developer guidance which enables hardened runtime.(Citation: Apple Developer Doco Hardened Runtime)
T1593 Application developers uploading to public code repositories should be careful to avoid publishing sensitive information such as credentials and API keys.
T1593.003 Application developers uploading to public code repositories should be careful to avoid publishing sensitive information such as credentials and API keys.
T1078 Ensure that applications do not store sensitive data or credentials insecurely. (e.g. plaintext credentials in code, published credentials in repositories, or credentials in public cloud storage).
```

Furthermore, you can easily extract the specifically required keys.

Comment: The JSON is presumably just partial, they omitted the parts that are irrelevant to the question. The question is about how to handle the techniques with no `comment` key. Your answer totally ignores the question.

Comment: the last 2 errors could be construed to be partial. However, the code certainly will not run with the first error. The fact is it does not run with any of the errors. This is fundamental and fixed.

Comment: That should be a comment on the original question. You still haven't shown how to solve the error from `technique['comment']` when there's no comment in a technique.

Comment: Since their code is actually getting past the `json.load()` call, it's clearly not a problem with the real JSON, just an incomplete copy to the question.

Comment: @Barmar,  thanks for pointing this out.  I have fixed this too. So now the errors are fixed and so is the code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify it was a quick snippet. There are no issues when using the full JSON file.

Comment: @TrashThrash,  that is fine.  Glad the question is answered.